# Row mapping in a dataframe through indexes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Problem: I started with a dataset that had customer IDs in it. But since I needed to fit a logistic regression I removed the IDs. After fitting the regression model I plotted a lift chart to see how much gain I have obtained as compared to the existing model.

I can see in % what's the lift but wanted to provide a dollar value for it. Inorder to do so I want to see how many cust Ids are present in top 20% of the lift region of the new model as compared to the existing model. I have built a similar use case related to my question.

```
set.seed(123)
id <- c('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10')
test_df1 <- data.frame(id=id, scr1= rnorm(10), scr2=rnorm(10))
test_df2 <- data.frame(id=id, scr1= rnorm(10), scr2=rnorm(10))

lift_df1 <- test_df1[order(test_df1$scr1,decreasing=TRUE),]
lift_df2 <- test_df2[order(test_df2$scr2,decreasing=TRUE),]

#performed fitting so removed ID
lift_df1$id <- NULL
lift_df2$id <- NULL

lift_df1_top5 <- head(lift_df1,0.5*nrow(lift_df1))
lift_df2_top5 <- head(lift_df2,0.5*nrow(lift_df2))
```

Now what I want to get is

1. In `lift_df1_top5` df get ID column back by mapping it against `test_df1`
2. Find out what are IDs present in `lift_df1_top5` that's not there in `lift_df2_top5`

I tried attempting it by myself but being a complete *noob* I couldn't get to an answer

```
lift_df1_top5$cust_id <- test_df1$id[as.numeric(rownames(lift_df1_top5))]
```

This works for the above case but when I try in actual code it introduces *NA* values so don't know why this is happening. 
Appreciate any help in this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is how to get the `IDs` back:

```
(A<-merge(lift_df1_top5,test_df1))[order(A[,1],decreasing = T),]
        scr1       scr2 id
5 1.71506499  1.7869131 a6
4 1.55870831  0.4007715 a3
3 0.46091621  0.4978505 a7
2 0.12928774 -0.5558411 a5
1 0.07050839  0.1106827 a4
```

Your second question: `ids` present in `lift_df1_top5` but not in `lift_df2_top5`:

```
> B=merge(lift_df2_top5,test_df2)
> A$id[!A$id%in%B$id]
factor(0)
Levels: a1 a10 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
```